# Looking for kml files

Tags: kml, polygon, country

I'm currently looking for kml files describing world countries polygones. The ones I found so far are too accurate and when I want to parse them in order to display the corresponding polygons, it is far too long!

So, do some of you know where I could get basic kml files (not too basic ;) I need to have a correct shape for the different countries but I really need to reduce the parsing complexity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen those at http://geocommons.com/ ?

Comment: No I didn't know this website. I've just had a look and there seems to be a few interesting leads. Thanks for the info ! CU !